# PHP or HTML first or does it matter?

Tags: php, html, syntax, tags

**I have a possible stupid question, but I'll ask it anyway.**

Does it matter what goes first, PHP or HTML code?

For example: Does PHP go before HTML, after HTML or does it matter at all?

```
<?php

echo "This is text";

?>


<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<font size="2">This is text</font>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Or:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<font size="2">This is text</font>
</center>
</body>
</html>

<?php

echo "This is text";

?>
```

---

**Or:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

echo "This is text";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like option #4. Keep the HTML and whatever controls it *separate* be it a "widget model" or "MVC" or "template" or whatever... (but, only one of the above will do what is actually required: `<? ?>` runs "in line".)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The third one is the correct way (assuming you want the text to echo out in the body).

PHP can jump in and out of HTML as you have shown above.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<font size="2"><?php echo "This is text"; ?></font>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Another useful example:

`<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php if($_GET["text"]=="a") { ?>
<center>
<font size="2">This is text a!</font>
</center>
<?php }
else { ?>
This is boring text.
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>`
There's a more correct way of doing it, you can read about that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). But this is better at illustrating my point.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I put the PHP as much as possible at the top of the page or even better outside the html page completely by using the html pages as purely views in the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Add your php code before the html code.

This allows you to change the out type, set requied variables, add http response headers if you require, etc.

You can have a lot of php embeded tags in between the html.

The html in your question would be invalid, if you echoed output before or after .
Make sure your out is valid html.

Don't be bad to the browser just cause they will try to work with whatever you give them.

Answer (score 4):

HTML doesn't go anywhere, but PHP script goes to server executes and response is returned to client side. Now that response is displayed/handled along with HTML code. HTML is only for browser where PHP script is used invoke service or do operations on database.
So, first PHP(Server) and then HTML(Client).

Answer (score 2):

Onlything you have to maintain valid html structure. so you canot put anything outside the `html` tag. so third option is the most valid thing. but if you use any of others, it will print anything you want.

Comment: @Fred: this is not the way of saying thanks in stack overflow. ;)

Comment: I'm new here (1 week), so takes a bit of getting used to. I found/read the tagged FAQs. Since all answers are good, I doubt I can accept all answers as good (?) I did upvote all though, if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Not being a php person, will try to ans this in general sense. HTML is for browsers and php is serverside. When your pages reaches to the browser, there is only HTML, while, if I am not wrong as php should behave similarly yo jsp, at serverside html is seen as simple strings that need to be printed out at stream. So ideally, this should not matter what come first.

From good practice perspective, as this is php code(in my case jsp) whose output will be html, I try to give more feel of java to my code file.