# JavaScript does not work when on my local MAMP server

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I recently uploaded my site to a MAMP server only to find that that the JavaScript failed to work. When viewed as a file on my computer the scripts work fine. However, now that my project is saved as a PHP file on my server, the JavaScript no longer works. The code below works fine on my computer, but not on the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Below I linked my website files via a public dropbox folder. The JavaScript is being called from the bottom of my index.php file (above the body tag), and the js folder contains the file bootstrap.js, which is the file I am having trouble calling.

```
<p>Some HTML</p>

<?
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("#");

$token = $_POST['#'];

try {
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"amount" => 2000, // amount in cents, again
"currency" => "usd",
"source" => $token,
"description" => "Example charge")
);
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

}

?>
```

Comment: Would you mind showing us some more of your code? Might be easier to catch something if there's a context!

Comment: give rest of the js code.... and the html file.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just added the requested files to my post. Thanks again, and I hope this is useful.

Comment: Would you copy the relevant snippets of code into your question please? Dropbox/repo/pasteboard links are prone to breakage, and we want questions here to be useful for future readers, long after you have fixed the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help and responses, but I found the culprit to my problem. The issue lied with how I placed my PHP scripts within the HTML. I made a simple error by placing my PHP between HTML and Javascript elements, which prevented the elements below my PHP from being executed. I found [this Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827545/php-or-html-first-or-does-it-matter) really helpful. Also thank you @bresson for pointing out the unnecessary slash in front of my "src=js/bootstrap.js", that helped.

**Instead of this:**

```
<p>Some HTML</p>

<?
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("#");

$token = $_POST['#'];

try {
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"amount" => 2000, // amount in cents, again
"currency" => "usd",
"source" => $token,
"description" => "Example charge")
);
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

}

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src= "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**I needed this:**

```
<p>Some HTML</p>


<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src= "js/bootstrap.js"></script> 

 <?
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("#");

$token = $_POST['#'];

try {
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"amount" => 2000, // amount in cents, again
"currency" => "usd",
"source" => $token,
"description" => "Example charge")
);
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the error (among others), I would look into the simplest fix possible and it looks like the file path to bootstrap.js may be incorrect (as humble.rumble mentioned). Try to pull the following bootstrap.js file from a CDN:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

Alternatively, your  file for bootstrap references bootstrap.js from the domain root:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Remove the slash "**/**js/bootstrap.js" and just reference bootstrap relative to index.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```